# ClassDefNotFound error in android

Tags: android, json

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                    HttpResponse response;
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    try{
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                        json.put("username", userName);
                        json.put("password", password);
                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        post.setEntity(se);
                        response = client.execute(post);
                        /*Checking response */
                        if(response!=null){
                            String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); //Get the data in the entity
                            JSONObject json2 = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(temp);

                            //JsonObject o = new JsonParser().parse(temp).getAsJsonObject();
                            Log.v("response", json2.get("state").toString());
                    }}
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
                    }
                }
              }).start();
```

I have this code and this returns the "temp" string. I wanted to parse this string to JSON object and I also added the json-simple 1.1.1.jar to my refferenced libraries. But the classnotfound error and classdeffound errors shows up in log cat. how to resolve this?

Comment: where you added jar file in the project

Comment: I added it via project properties -> add external jar files it automatically goes to a newly created referenced libraries folder.

Comment: You should also put it to /libs folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't add jar files like that..follow these steps

You should try this:

1. `Remove` all references to the `JAR` in your project from Java `project -> properties -> Java build path -> libraries`
2. Create a `libs` folder if not exist at the root of your project Copy the `JAR` into the libs folder.
3. If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

clean your project and run. it will work

Comment: Hey There is a folder called libs containing file android-support-v4.jar but I can not add any external jar file into that. It does not allow to copy from the referenced library. How could I do it?

Comment: just copy and past your jar file into that libs folder.

Comment: I tried to import them in eclipse. anyway it works fine. Thank you very much.