# Android library - ClassDefNotFoundError - class not in classes.dex

Tags: android

I have an Android library (Java code) that I share among multiple Android application projects using Eclipse.  For application projects I've created in the past I'm able to reference the Android library and use it at runtime no problem.  But now for any new Android application project I create with references to my library, I get ClassDefNotFoundErrors whenever I reference classes in the library at runtime.

This is only a problem for Android libraries; for general Java libraries I'm still able to reference them from new Android application projects no problem.

Using dex2jar I found that in my application's classes.dex file the library's classes are *not* present.  Whereas for my older application projects where everything works, the library's classes *are* present in classes.dex.

Note that the working-case apps and the non-working-case apps both reference the same Eclipse project on disk.  So the problem is not in the library eclipse project, but rather in the application Eclipse project.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?  Or more generally how to debug the process by which Eclipse creates the Android application's classes.dex?

Here's a screenshot of the application project, referencing my "testlib" Android library project. I've tried moving the reference up and down the list, checking the checkbox, etc.
[image]

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: you have any libraries in the project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any libraries in your project just look at my answer here [ClassDefNotFound error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511271/964741) it will solve your problem ..